# CentOS-7 как настроить авто очистку лог файлов access_log?

Tags: linux, логирование, centos7

Подскажите как настроить авто очистку лог файлов access_log и error_log?

Comment: ключевое слово: logrotate

Comment: *logrotate* здесь, скоре всего, не поможет. Ведь *access_log* - скоре всего, относится к некоему серверу (HTTP, CUPS,...) и должны "рулиться" настройками самого сервера. Поясняю: файл *access_log* (ЕМНИП) должен присутствовать в каждом виртуальном сервере *Apache*, а вот сколько их и где они располагаются, знает только сам *Apache*.

Comment: Руками чищу, времени 5 минут раз в месяц и надежно.

Answer (score 1):

это делается через logrotate

есть файл /etc/logrotate.d/httpd

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
missingok
notifempty
sharedscripts
delaycompress
postrotate
    /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
endscript
}
```

поставь там

```
rotate 10
```

и они будут удаляться более 10 штук, естественно в этом месте /var/log/httpd/ и если они называются с .log на конце

в конфиге в апаче исправь имена фалов с access_log на access.log